# A pyinstller error: IOError

Tags: pyinstaller, ioerror

When I use pyinstaller I met a problem that I don't know how to solve:

```
IOError:[Errno 22]: invalid mode <'wb'> or 
filename:'C:Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp;D:\\academic software\\python\\me_test_exe.tmp'
```

Comment: That filename doesn't look right. Please post the code where you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of the space in the file path. Try renaming the directory

'academic software' to 'academic_software'.

If this solves the error, this is a bad piece of code :).